# What is unit testing, and does it require code being written?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I've joined a new team, and I've had a problem understanding how they are doing unit tests. When I asked where the unit tests are written, they explained they don't do their unit tests that way.

They explained that what they're calling unit tests is when they actually check the code they wrote locally, and that all of the points are being connected. To me, this is integration testing and just testing your code locally.

I was under the impression that unit tests are code written to verify behavior in a small section of a code. For example, you may write a unit test to make sure it returns the right value, and make the appropriate calls to the database. use a framework like NUnit or MbUnit to help you out in your assertions.

Unit testing to me is supposed to be fast and quick. To me, you want these so you can automate it, and have a huge suite of tests for your application to make sure that it behaves AS YOU EXPECT.

Can someone provide clarification in my or their misunderstandings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct.

Doing a project without unit-tests (as they do, don't be fooled) might seem nice for the first few weeks: less code to write, less architecture to think about, less problems to worry about.  And you can see the code is working correctly, right?

But as soon as someone (someone else, or even the original coder) comes back to an existing piece of code to modify it, add feature, or simply understand how it worked and what it exactly did, things will become a lot more problematic. And before you realize it, you'll spend your nights browsing through log files and debugging what seemed like a small feature just because it needs to integrate with other code that nobody knows exactly how it works. ANd you'll hate your job.

If it's not worth testing it (with actual unit-tests), then it's not worth writing the code in the first place. Everyone who tried coding without and with unit tests know that. Please, please, make them change their mind. Every time a piece of untested code is checked in somewhere, a puppy dies horribly.

Also, I should say, it's a lot (A LOT) harder to add tests later to a project that was done without testing in mind, than to build the test and production code side-to-side from the very start. Testing not only help you make sure your code works fine, it *improves* your code quality by forcing you to make good decisions (i.e. coding on interfaces, loose coupling, inversion of control, etc.)

Comment: I'm all for unit tests. I've done it on my projects for the past two years. My supervisor knows this, and knows how I am fond of them. This is part of the reason he put me here. I just have a hard time trying to understand why they're calling what they're doing "unit testing".

Comment: Probably because they don't know better. Show them the light :)

Answer (score 7):

I have worked places that did testing that way and called it unit testing. It reminded me of a quote attributed to Abe Lincoln:

Lincoln: How many legs does a dog have?

Other Guy: 4.

Lincoln: What if we called the tail a leg?

Other Guy: Well, then it would have 5.

Lincoln: No, the answer is still 4. Calling a tail a leg doesn't make it so.

Comment: A good answer. Note that apparently Lincoln's story was actually [about a calf](http://timpanogos.wordpress.com/2007/05/23/lincoln-quote-sourced-calfs-tail-not-dogs-tail/).

Comment: I'm all for bringing true unit tests into the application (I need to learn the pain points first though).  But I think having them using the wrong terms currently is going to create problems. How do I get them to stop using the term "unit testing" to describe what they're doing?

Comment: @Gasik: Changing a corporate culture is one of the harder things to do in development. It depends a lot on your development team too. Small, open team might benefit from an email linking to some descriptions of unit tests. Team is a "strong" manager (note I don't say dictator) probably benefit from a one on one with the boss. Of course, leading by example tends to help also.

Answer (score 5):

> They explained that what they're calling unit tests is when they
>   actually check the code they wrote locally, and that all of the points
>   are being connected.

That is not a unit test.  That is a code review.  Code reviews are good, but without actual unit tests things will break.

Unit tests involve writing code.  Specifically, a unit test operate on one unit, which is just a class or component of your software.

If a class under test depends on another class, and you test both classes together, you have an integration test.  Integration tests are good.  Depending on the language/framework you might use the same testing framework (e.g. junit for java) for both unit and integration tests.  If you have a dependency but mock or stub that dependency, then you have a pure unit test.

> Unit testing to me is supposed to be fast and quick. To me, you want
>   these so you can automate it, and have a huge suite of tests for your
>   application to make sure that it behaves AS YOU EXPECT.

That is essentially correct.  How 'fast and quick' developing unit tests is depends on the complexity of what is being tested and the skill of the developer writing the test.  You definitely want to build up a suite of tests over time, so you know when something breaks as a codebase becomes more complex.  That is how testing makes your codebase more maintainable, by telling you what ceases to function as you make changes.

Answer (score 4):

Your team-mates are not doing unit testing.  They are doing "fly by the seat of your pants" development.

Answer (score 2):

**"Unit testing" != "unit tests".**

Writing unit tests is one specific method of performing unit testing.  It is a very good one, and if your unit tests are written well, it can give you good value over a long time.  But what they're doing is indeed unit testing.  It's just the kind of unit testing that doesn't help you **at all** the next time you need to carve on the same code.  And that's wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

To add my two cents, yes, that is indeed not Unit testing. IMHO, the main features of unit tests are that it should be fast, automated and isolated. You can using a mocking framework such as RhinoMocks to isolate external dependencies.

Unit tests also have to be very simple and short. Ideally no more than a screen length. It is also one of the few places in software engineering where copy and pasting code might be a better solution than creating highly reusable and highly abstract functions. The reason simplicity is given such a high priority is to avoid the "Who watches the Watchers" problem. You really don't want to be in a situation where you have complex bugs in your unit tests, because they themselves aren't being tested. Here you are relying on the extreme simplicity and tiny size of the tests to avoid bugs.

The names of the unit tests also should be very descriptive, again following the simplicity and self documenting paradigm. I should be able to read the name of the test method and know exactly what it is doing. A quick glance at the code should show me exactly what functionality is being tested and if any external dependencies are being mocked.

The descriptive test names also make you think about the application as a whole. If I look at the entire test run, ideally just by looking at the names of all the tests that were run, I should have a fairly good idea of what the application does.